# Bash rm /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, linux-kernel, rm, selinux

I have **created this file `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` couple of months ago** on my **centos 7** server to disable ping requests permanently and now I can not undo this!

I'm logged in as `root` user but still **can not use command `rm /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` to remove this file!** I even checked immutable bit and its not set on that file... I get the same error:

> rm: cannot remove ‘/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all’:
>   Permission denied

But magically i can edit file with `nano` without errors but editing not cause any chances to enable icmp ping requests again! I think it must be removed but seems to be impossible!

can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

You can’t delete that file. To re-enable ICMP echoes you need to write 0 to it; as root:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

Comment: I have done this before and one time again now but it not worked in my case and still server is not replying to any ping requests.

Comment: That suggests that you’ve disable other ICMP settings, or maybe that pings are blocked by your firewall...